# Explicit relation between the regularization parameters in Ivanov and Tikhonov regularization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, nonlinear-optimization, regularization

Consider the class of functions $\mathcal H_\phi $ defined by
$$\mathcal H_\phi :=\left\{h:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R\mid h(x) = \langle w,\phi(x)\rangle+b,\ (w,b)\in\mathbb R^D\times\mathbb R\right\} $$
Where $\phi : \mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^D$ is a *mapping function*. Assume that we are given an empirical loss function $\hat L$ and we want to solve the following problem
$$h : \arg\min_{\mathcal H_\phi} \hat L(h) \tag 1$$
Solving $(1)$ can be thought of as solving a [soft-margin SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine#Soft-margin) problem.

To solve $(1)$ while avoiding [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), a common approach is to add a penalty term on the $\ell_2$ norm of the weight vector $w$, which is called $L_2$ or *Tikhonov regularization* :
$$h_\lambda : \arg\min_{\mathcal H_\phi} \hat L(h) + \frac\lambda 2\|w\|^2\tag 2 $$
Alternatively, another approach is to directly constrain the weight vector to remain bounded in a certain radius. This is called *Ivanov regularization* :
$$h_R : \arg\min_{\mathcal H_\phi} \hat L(h),\ \text{ s.t. } \|w\|^2\le R^2\tag 3$$
In their paper [Tikhonov, Ivanov and Morozov regularization for support vector machine learning (2016)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-015-5540-x), Oneto et al. proved, under the assumption that $\hat L$ is convex with respect to $w$, that a Tikhonov regularized SVM is equivalent to an Ivanov-regularized SVM, in the following sense :

> **Theorem :** For any $\lambda$, there exists an $R \equiv R(\lambda)\in\mathbb R$ such that problems $(2)$ and $(3)$ have the same solutions (i.e. such that $h_\lambda = h_R$).

Regarding this theorem, I mainly have two questions :

- How does $R(\lambda)$ vary with respect to $\lambda$ ? Is it at least continuous ? Is it possible to get any lower bound on it in terms of $\lambda$ ? Intuitively, one would expect that $R(\lambda)\to\infty$ continuously as $\lambda \to 0$, but my attempts to prove it failed, and the proof given in the paper is not constructive so it doesn't help.
- Does this result apply to more general families of functions ? In particular, I am interested in Deep Neural Networks. In that case the convexity assumption on $\hat L$ does not hold anymore and it seems unlikely that the authors' approach will work. But intuitively again, one would expect that adding a penalty on the Euclidean norm of the weight parameters would correspond to restricting the parameters to remain in a ball whose radius depends on the strength of the penalty.

I will be grateful for any help or useful references you may provide.

Comment: This is a super important question - I don't know the answer, but many folks sortof handwave the equivalence between a hard constraint and the fact that *for the right parameter* we can just add it to the objective function, paying no mind to the fact that one can never determine the correct parameter to do so (unless perhaps with some post-hoc analysis with a true solution handy)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that for $\lambda>0$ problem (2) is solvable with solution $w_\lambda$. If $\hat L$ is convex, then  a solution exists and is unique.

Now take $\lambda<\lambda'$, and let $w$ and $w'$ be the associated solutions. Then by optimality
$$\begin{split}
L(w) + \frac\lambda2\|w\|^2& \le L(w') + \frac\lambda2\|w'\|^2\\
&\le  L(w')+ \frac{\lambda'}2\|w'\|^2 + \frac{\lambda-\lambda'}2\|w'\|^2\\
&\le  L(w) + \frac{\lambda'}2\|w\|^2 + \frac{\lambda-\lambda'}2\|w'\|^2.\\
\end{split}
$$
This shows
$$
0 \le (\lambda - \lambda')( \|w'\|^2 - \|w\|^2) 
$$
and $\lambda \mapsto \|w_\lambda\|$ is monotonically decreasing, as expected.
If the problem has a solution for $\lambda=0$ then we can use the corresponding solution $w_0$ to get $\|w_\lambda\| \le \|w_0\|$.

Now set $R(\lambda):=\|w_\lambda\|$. Take $w$ such that $\|w\|\le R(\lambda)$. Then by optimality of $w_\lambda$ we have
$$
\hat L(w(\lambda)) + \frac\lambda 2\|w_\lambda\|^2
\le 
\hat L(w) + \frac\lambda 2\|w\|^2
\le 
\hat L(w) + \frac\lambda 2\|w_\lambda\|^2,
$$
that is, $w_\lambda$ solves (3).

If $\hat L$ is convex then $\lambda \mapsto \|w_\lambda\|$ is continuous. Let me prove this for differentiable $\hat L$, the same proof works with subgradients as well.
Again let $0<\lambda<\lambda'$, and let $w$ and $w'$ be the associated solutions.
Then
$$
\nabla \hat L(w) + \lambda w = 0 = \nabla \hat L(w') + \lambda'w'.
$$
Rearranging and multiplying with $w-w'$ gives
$$
\lambda \|w-w'\|^2 = (\nabla \hat L(w')  - \nabla \hat L(w))^T (w-w') + (\lambda'-\lambda) (w')^T(w-w').
$$
The first addend on the right-hand side is non-positive due to convexity of $\hat L$, which implies
$$
\lambda \|w-w'\|^2 \le (\lambda'-\lambda) (w')^T(w-w').
$$
The rhs tends to zero for $|\lambda - \lambda|\to 0$, and the continuity follows.

To summarize: if we set $R(\lambda):=\|w_\lambda\|$, then $R$ is monotonically decreasing, it is bounded if there is a solution in case $\lambda=0$, it is continuous if $\hat L$ is convex.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for your answer ! Also, I think that the first part of your argument still applies when the solutions $w$ and $w'$ are not unique, which is good news for me :)

Comment: Yes, that is true. Convexity is needed for continuity, otherwise solutions may jump for varying $\lambda$.