# When could a small perturbation in the objective function leave the solution set unchanged?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, regularization

Let $R: \mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R^+$ be an (almost everywhere) twice differentiable function we want to minimize. For $\lambda\ge0 $, define the $\lambda$-regularized objective as
$$ \min_{\theta\in \mathbb R^p}\ \underbrace{R(\theta) + \frac\lambda2|\theta|^2 }_{=:\ R_\lambda(\theta)}, \tag1$$
where $|\cdot|$ is the standard Euclidean norm. $R$ is not convex, so the argmin of $R_\lambda$ is not reduced to a single point.

I have the following question :

> does there exist a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that
>
> $$\arg\min_{\theta\in\Theta} R_\lambda(\theta) =\arg\min_{\theta\in\Theta} R(\theta) \ \text{ for all } \lambda\in[0,\varepsilon] \ ?$$

(again, note that these argmins are *not* singletons). In words, does adding a sufficiently small perturbation leave the optimization problem unchanged ?

I expect this to be possible, since by a Lagrangian optimization argument, it is possible to show that problem $(1)$ is equivalent to minimizing $R(\theta)$ under the constraint that $\theta$ remains in a ball whose radius is a non-increasing function of $\lambda$, so for vanishingly small values of $\lambda$ the constraint should not be active (see e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401212/showing-the-equivalence-between-the-l-2-norm-regularized-regression-and), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191603/ridge-regression-formulation-as-constrained-versus-penalized-how-are-they-equiv?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-015-5540-x)).

It has however been shown in an answer to [this previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4697222/regularized-optimization-adding-a-vanishingly-small-penalty-term-does-not-chan) that such an $\varepsilon$ need not exist in general. Hence **I am looking for a general enough sufficient condition under which the answer to my question is positive**.

Thanks in advance for your help.